# script not executed when accessing the page from external ip, the request is pending as it never happens:

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I opened the port 3000 in my router and I am trying to load a page with a script served in express from my public ip. The strange is that if I access my public ip from the wifi the port is opened the script runs completely, but when trying to access it from other wifi the script does not run completely.

I have two servers, the first server is:

```
//this is the server exposed in my public ip
//I can access it from my wifi and external wifi (internet)
const express = require('express')
const http = require("http");
const path = require('path');
const fs = require("fs");
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
app.use(cors({
  origin : '*'
}));

app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
//this runs both from my wifi and external wifi
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/html');
res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, "./scripts", "index.html"));
});
const PORT = 3000;
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is listening on https://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

The second server is:

```
const express = require('express')
const http = require("http");
const app = express();
const httpServer = http.createServer(app);
app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
  console.log("request arrived");
/*
this only runs when accesing my public ip from my wifi, but not from external wifi
*/
  res.send("hello")
})
const PORT = 3300;
httpServer.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("3300 working");
});
```

The index.html file served by the first server is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Server</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>server working</h1>
    <script>
        console.log("script running"); //this runs both from my wifi and external wifi
        function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback) { 
//function only runs when using my wifi
            var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
                    callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
            }
            xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true);  
            xmlHttp.send(null);
        }
        httpGetAsync("http://localhost:3300/", (res) => { //connects to the second server
            console.log(res); 
/*
console log with value "hello" from second server appears if try to access the external ip from my wifi, but if I try to access from 
a device not connected to my wifi the httpGetAsync() function does not run. It seems the httpGetAsync() function is being blocked when accesing from external wifi.
*/
        })
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

This is a screenshot of the devTools when trying to execute the httpGetAsync() function from external wifi:
[image]

I want the httpGetAsync() function to run when accesing my public ip (first server) from an external wifi (internet).

Comment: i think it is not cors issue, but due to the use of a non-standard port, which is blocked

Comment: Thanks for answering @AlexeyObukhov, I changed the first server port for 8080 and the second for 80, now I can see two errors in the console log, the first error is: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'xxx:80/' from origin 'xxx:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space `private`.  The second error is: GET xxx:80 net::ERR_FAILED. I am researching this.